# Detect if a question matches another question with python or js?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, module, nlp-question-answering

I'm trying to find out how I can detect if one question matches another with python or JS. For example
detect that the question:

```
"Does anyone know the MySql password?"
```

is related to the question

```
"Does anyone know the MySql password?"
```

in order to give an automatic answer while limiting the number of false positives.

Comment: your examples are incorrect (both phrases are equal), but in general this is a complex problem involving some advanced mathematics. Start by defining more formally what you mean by "phrase A is related to the phrase B".

Comment: What does "related" mean here because those strings are _identical_. You should add a [mcve] to your question, and maybe limit it to either Python _or_ JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`

```
let str1="Does anyone know the MySql password?"; 
let str2="Does anyone know the MySql password?";

let parsedStr1=str1.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g,''); 
let parsedStr2=str1.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g,'');

parsedStr1.localeCompare(parsedStr2);

/* Expected Returns:

 0:  exact match

-1:  string_a < string_b

 1:  string_a > string_b

*/
```

`